# What is the best practice to show a picker popup without a visible picker in .net maui?

Tags: .net, maui, picker

I want to show the "result"/ the popup, which is shown, when i focus a picker in a .net maui app.

The "problem" is, i don't have a visible picker element. I just want to show the picker selection popup programmatically.

What is the best practice to do this?

I expect the popup, which is shown, when i focus a picker in a .net maui app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior of pickers depends very much of the platform you are on.

Focusing the picker is not enough on windows.
You need to click "enter" after that to open it.

On android you need to do platform click.

(Those problems get from bugged, to fixed then to bugged again, when maui version change, not even sure in what state they are currently)

If you want invisible picker , with visible popup, it is very easy - you need a picker that is **visible, but with Opacity of 0**.

This is very common workaround, that I have seen in more than one place.
Never used it myself.

Anyway, if you want to present a choice, and you do not care about the picker itself, a popup is also possible solution.

This is what I am using:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup

I do not know what you are planning to do, there are bugs with both approaches.
Pick the one that works best for you.

Here, the dark magic you requested:

```
#if WINDOWS
var handler = myPicker.Handler as IPickerHandler;
handler.PlatformView.IsDropDownOpen = true;
#endif
```

Comment: Hm, du you have an idea how to press enter on the picker on windows programmatically? Thanks.

Comment: I do not write specifically for windows, and last time I checked there was "feature request" about it.

Comment: @Dryzler I added some code, if you find nothing better.

Comment: nice, the windows code does work!